# How to put the txt file in the Downloads directory (python, odoo)

Tags: python, file, save, odoo

```
    a = random.randint(1, 9999)
    name = 'filename' + str(a * 7) + '.txt'
    print '>>', a
    ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.sep)
    filepath = os.path.join(ROOT, name)
    os.chdir(filepath)
    file = open(filepath, 'w')
```

It shows an OSError.
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Downloads'

Comment: can you show the entire output of the script?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `os.chdir` to a file. Your variable `name` is the filename ending in `.txt` which you are appending to `ROOT`. Just change directory before you're adding the filename to your `filepath` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the line os.chdir(filepath), no need to change to the directory. Use the below code.

```
a = random.randint(1, 9999)
name = 'filename' + str(a * 7) + '.txt'
print '>>', a
ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.sep)
filepath = os.path.join(ROOT, name)
file = open(filepath, 'w')
```

Comment: Thank you.. It worked, there's no error OSError already but it says, 
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/filename6839.txt'

what should I do with the permission?

Comment: File is saving in the root location /. So there is no permission to save the to that user, thats why that error comes, To resolve this, you need to set the permission to read/write by user to that location.